# Fail to connect to postgis from arcgis pro

Tags: postgis, arcgis

I believe I have the postgis (install, extension, etc) set up.

[image]

But I cannot connect to postgres from arcgis pro.

[image]

I have tried to connect to my geodatabase from Postgis bundle, and it connected and successfully added in the shapefile:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under `instance`, you must specify the server (`localhost`). The port is the default and you can omit it.

... and then read this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271308/database-connection-error-invalid-database-name/271310#271310) as it won't work with DB names not being lower-case